# Убрать класс active в jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

При нажатии на "Итем2" и после этого при нажатии на "Итем1" - получается, что оба item'a имеют класс `active` и они начинают неадекватно себя вести.

Как поправить item'ы, чтобы, при раскрытом "Итем2", я кликнул на "Итем1", "Итем2" свернулся и открылся "Итем2".

```js
$('.ti-main-item').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  if ($(".tog-inf-content").is(":visible")) {
    $(".tog-inf-content").slideUp();
  } else {
    $(".active .tog-inf-content").slideToggle();
  }
});
```

```css
.ti-main-item .tog-inf-content {
  display: none;
}

.ti-main-item .fa-long-arrow-down {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}

.ti-main-item.active .fa-long-arrow-down {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="ti-main-item">
  <a href="#" class="tog-inf-nav">
    <span class="ti-head">Итем1</span>
    <span class="ti-arrow"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-down"></i></span>
  </a>
  <div class="tog-inf-content">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Описание</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Описание</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Описание</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Описание</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="ti-main-item">
  <a href="#" class="tog-inf-nav">
    <span class="ti-head">Итем2</span>
    <span class="ti-arrow"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-down"></i></span>
  </a>
  <div class="tog-inf-content">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Описание</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Описание</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Описание</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Описание</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.ti-main-item').click(function() {
    // Toggle current menu
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('.tog-inf-content', $(this)).slideToggle();

    // Hide siblings
    var siblings = $(this).siblings();
    siblings.removeClass('active');
    $('.tog-inf-content', siblings).slideUp();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(".test")` вернет вам массив из всех элементов с данным селектором. И выполнит функцию на первом. Поэтому такой вариант не подходит. Нужно искать соответствующий элемент в контексте, вот так:

```
var $content = $(this).find(".tog-inf-content");
```

```js
$('.ti-main-item').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  var $content = $(this).find(".tog-inf-content");
  if ($content.is(":visible")) {
   $content.slideUp();
  } else {
    $content.slideToggle();
  }
});
```

```css
.ti-main-item .tog-inf-content {
  display: none;
}

.ti-main-item .fa-long-arrow-down {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}

.ti-main-item.active .fa-long-arrow-down {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="ti-main-item">
  <a href="#" class="tog-inf-nav">
    <span class="ti-head">Итем1</span>
    <span class="ti-arrow"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-down"></i></span>
  </a>
  <div class="tog-inf-content">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Описание</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Описание</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Описание</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Описание</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="ti-main-item">
  <a href="#" class="tog-inf-nav">
    <span class="ti-head">Итем2</span>
    <span class="ti-arrow"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-down"></i></span>
  </a>
  <div class="tog-inf-content">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Описание</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Описание</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Описание</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Описание</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```